# Prevent Mutt from asking me to recall a postponed message when composing

Tags: mutt

When I compose a message with Mutt, Mutt first asks me if I would like to recall a postponed message. I do not want Mutt to ask me this. Can I tell Mutt to skip this step and get straight to the composing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That behaviour is controlled by the `recall` [option](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#recall), which defaults to `ask-yes`.  You can skip that by setting it to `no`:

```
set recall=no
```